# Raspberry pi PHP display code instead of output

Tags: php, apache-httpd

I installed php services and Apache2 on my raspberry pi without errors. But, when I opened a browser and entered my page URL, it wrote

```
<?php echo "Hello";?>
```

instead of `Hello`.

I have tried reinstalling and have checked that the Apache PHP module is installed and enabled with `a2enmod`, the script runs fine when run directly with `php` on the terminal.

Anyone know how to fix that? Thanks for any help

Comment: What web server are you using and what's the name of the file containing your PHP script? You may need to configure your web server to *execute* the file with `php` and send the output to the browser rather than send the contents to the browser as-is.

Comment: webserver is apache2 and how can i configure webserver? Name of file is index.php

Comment: Can you add the extra information to your question about using Apache2, confirming the `libapache2-mod-php` is installed and configured and that you can run the script from the terminal without errors. Maybe also add the installation steps you've followed to get to this point?

Comment: If i knew how to confirm it, i would do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the whole RPI and installed all things again, not sure what caused the problem but it worked

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Fact assumption table]
Fact assumption table

Solution 1

Try your script without the tags. It's possible that Apache automatically runs the script through PHP only and not HTML with PHP. This will mean that it sees echo 'Hello' only if it understands the rest of the code. If it is only running PHP it might not understand the tags and just print out the whole thing. There's a slim chance but try it out just in case. See if that will help.

Solution 2

Your web browser may not support PHP. You should check what web browser you're using. If you're using Midori, it might not support it. Try doing this on a different device and accessing another browser like Google Chrome.

Solution 3

Make sure that your file extension is not .txt - This might be the reason for it not seeing and not compiling your code.

Solution 4

> Taken from [this stackoverflow question](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page&ved=2ahUKEwi3q77nut_gAhUH0YMKHffDDUsQFjABegQIDRAG&usg=AOvVaw04RJbEwbLPb9yZQ8kyaf5b)

Make sure that Apache's httpd.conf file has the PHP MIME type in it. This should be something like AddType application/x-httpd-php .php . This tells Apache to run .php files as PHP.

IF ALL ELSE FAILS, TRY TO USE PHP WITH A DIFFERENT COMPILER.

Possible links that may help:

[Another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495)
.
[PHP.net](https://php.net/install)
.
[If your HTTPS.config file is wrong](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html)

I hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: At first i wanna say thanks for help, and for the second none of solutions helped, i removed php tags and tried on other browsers and different devices and it showed echo "Hello"; istead of Hello

Comment: This seems like a problem for Apache and not Raspberry Pi then, here are some links for a question that is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page ••• Here's another link as well: http://php.net/install

Comment: I know that too, but that page didnt helped me

Comment: Ok, I'll sketch up a fact - assumption sheet and get back to you soon

Comment: P.S. is it possible that the file extension is not .php? That could be the cause of all this.

Comment: I added the table in the answer, that was all I had...

Comment: Nothing helped :/

Comment: Maybe you have to reconfigure the compiler.

Comment: P.S. I edited my answer

Comment: Try using a different compiler

Comment: "Make sure that Apache's httpd.conf file has the PHP MIME type in it. This should be something like AddType application/x-httpd-php .php . This tells Apache to run .php files as PHP" . https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page&ved=2ahUKEwi3q77nut_gAhUH0YMKHffDDUsQFjABegQIDRAG&usg=AOvVaw04RJbEwbLPb9yZQ8kyaf5b

Comment: Well, my etc/apache2 is missing httpd.conf

Comment: Then you should probably make the file and write what you need to.

Comment: Try writing -l into the command line for Apache to see which modules are set up and working. If it shows PHP as one then we are on the wrong track.

Comment: If it is a loaded module problem, use this site to help: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html